# Django - Posting jQuery dictionary via Ajax prints None in views.py

Tags: python, django

I have an Ajax function in my Django project resembling the following...

```
$('#btn-submit').click(function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  var btn = $(this);
  var dataUrl = btn.attr('data-href');
  var title = $('#title').val();
  var dict = {};
  $('.choice-m2m-check').each(function(i){
    k = $(this).val();
    v = $(this).attr('data-value');
    dict[k] = v;
  });
  $.ajax({
    url:dataUrl,
    method:'POST',
    data:{
      'title':title,
      'dict':dict,
    },
    success:function(data){
      if (data.saved){
        ...
      }
    },
    error:function(error){
      ...
    }
  });
});
```

So I have a `{key: value, ...}` dictionary which assigns a 'true' or 'false' boolean flag to each item. This is then posted to the URL represented by 'dataUrl' where Python does some checks on the data.

So firstly, in the jQuery after the key value pairs have been assigned, I console log the value of dict using `console.log(dict)` which gives me something like the following `{item-885564895: "true", item-0385245877: "false"}` in the console.

The problem is that in my Django view where I print the posted value of `request.POST.get('dict')` then it prints `None`. Note that when I print the 'title' field which is a regular string then printing it returns the value of the title. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: As far as I know you can *not* transfer a Javascript object. You will need to `JSON.stringify(..)` it at the client side (and optionally parse it again at the server side).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As far as I know you can *not* send a JavaScript object as payload in a HTTP request. After all JavaScript constists out of more than only dictionaries, integers, strings, etc. How would you for example transfer a `function` to the server? How is the server supposed to handle that?

What you thus need is some sort of *format*: a way to *encode* the data to a type that can be used as payload: a string. Now standard JavaScript objects have a popular format: the **J**ava**S**cript **O**bject **N**otation, or in short JSON.

We can thus encode the `dict` entry to a JSON string with `JSON.stringify(..)`:

```
$('#btn-submit').click(function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  var btn = $(this);
  var dataUrl = btn.attr('data-href');
  var title = $('#title').val();
  var dict = {};
  $('.choice-m2m-check').each(function(i){
    k = $(this).val();
    v = $(this).attr('data-value');
    dict[k] = v;
  });
  $.ajax({
    url:dataUrl,
    method:'POST',
    data:{
      'title': title,
      'dict': JSON.stringify(dict),
    },
    success:function(data){
      if (data.saved){
        ...
      }
    },
    error:function(error){
      ...
    }
  });
});
```

Now of course the Django backend will not *automatically* transfer this into Python objects: it sees a string and hence handles it as a string. But JSON can be decoded in vanilla Pyhon objects (a `dict`, `bool`, etc.) with `json.loads`:

```
from json import loads as jsonloads

def my_view(request):
    mydict = jsonloads(request.POST.get('dict'))
    # process mydict
    # ...
    pass
```

Answer (score 0):

Error seems to be on js side. It looks like the title field have same id and name i.e. title. So when the button is clicked, the form got submitted directly without calling this function. Better try adding logs in this function. If the button is added dynamically, then try using below

```
$('#btn-submit').on('click',function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  alert("This function called")  
});
```